# Is PHP Drupal 7's templating language? Is ".tpl.php" just a label in a PHP filename on technical grounds, or is it something other than normal PHP?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, templating

As I'm learning, Drupal's templating files turn out to PHP files. Now on technical grounds, in terms of how they are executed and interpreted, are they just PHP files that are used as templates, so they can be treated technically as PHP files under XYZ condition, or are they parsed and treated as non-PHP or as some special or modified PHP?

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://drupal.org/node/171194) gives details about how the themes function in Drupal.

**template files (.tpl.php)**

> These templates are used for the (x)HTML markup and PHP variables. In
>   some situations they may output other types of data --xml rss for
>   example. Each .tpl.php file handles the output of a specific themable
>   chunk of data, and in some situations it can handle multiple .tpl.php
>   files through suggestions. They are optional, and if none exists in
>   your theme it will fall back to the default output. Refrain from
>   having complex logic in these files. In most cases, it should be
>   straight (x)HTML tags and PHP variables. A handful of these templates
>   exist in directories where core and contributed modules exist. Copying
>   them to your theme folder will force Drupal to read your version.

Also, if you want a detailed explanation on what a TPL file is, irrespective of the system in which it is used then you can look at [this link.](http://file-extension.paretologic.com/detail.php/File-Extension-tpl)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [theme api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/7), it says this:

> Drupal's default template renderer is a simple PHP parsing engine that includes the template and stores the output. Drupal's theme engines can provide alternate template engines, such as XTemplate, Smarty and PHPTal. The most common template engine is PHPTemplate (included with Drupal and implemented in phptemplate.engine, which uses Drupal's default template renderer.

When it says "parsing engine" I'm not sure how much parsing actually goes on. I believe for template files, it just includes the source during processing, and caches the result when appropriate.

So to answer your question, you should be able to put any php code you like in your tpl.php files, although ideally, these files will only contain basic php used for logic and printing values.